# Evaluation involving complex conjugates

Tags: complex, core-language

I was trying to write an expression involving `Conjugate`. To create a minimal example, however, I have reduced it down to these expressions.

```
(a1 + I b1 + a1 - I b1) \[Element] Reals
(a1 + I b1 + a1 - I b1) \[Element] Complexes
(a1 + I b1 + a1 - I b1) \[Element] Integers
```

[image]

I am trying to understand why the first expression evaluates differently.

---

Some basics:

```
Head /@ {2 + 3 I, Complex[2, 3], a + I b, Complex[a, b]}
```

> {Complex, Complex, Plus, Complex}

```
Conjugate /@ {2 + 3 I, Complex[2, 3], a + I b, Complex[a, b]}
```

> ```
> {2 - 3 I, 2 - 3 I, Conjugate[a] - I Conjugate[b], 
>  Conjugate[Complex[a, b]]}
> ```

```
ComplexExpand[(Conjugate /@ {2 + 3 I, Complex[2, 3], a + I b, 
    Complex[a, b]})]
```

> `{2 - 3 I, 2 - 3 I, a - I b, Complex[a, b]}`

Notice behavior of `Complex[a,b]` above compared to `Complex[2,3]`.

---

For more context:

```
z1 = a1 + I b1;
(z1 + Conjugate[z1] // ComplexExpand)
```

> 2 a1

```
Assuming[{a1, a2, b1, b2} \[Element] Reals, 
 FullSimplify[((z1 + Conjugate[z1]) // ComplexExpand) \[Element] 
   Complexes]]
Assuming[{a1, a2, b1, b2} \[Element] Reals, 
 FullSimplify[((z1 + Conjugate[z1]) // ComplexExpand) \[Element] 
   Reals]]
```

A complex number added to its conjugate returns a real number. How do I write that in Mathematica using assumptions on a1, b1 etc?

Comment: `Block[{a, b, z = a + I*b}, Simplify[z + Conjugate[z] ∈ Reals, {a, b} ∈ Reals]]  (* True *)`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. `z - Conjugate[z]` should evaluate to False but it doesn't. If you change `Reals` with `Complexes` it seems to require `ComplexExpand` that I was trying to use initially.

Comment: Add the `b != 0` assumption, like this `Block[{a, b, z = a + I*b}, Simplify[z - Conjugate[z] ∉ Reals, {{a, b} ∈ Reals, b != 0}]] (*True*)`  or `Block[{a, b, z = a + I*b}, 
 Simplify[z - Conjugate[z] \[Element] Complexes, {{a, b} \[Element] Reals, b != 0}]](*True*)`

Comment: Note that `Complex[a, b]` is not a valid complex number. If `a` and `b` ever evaluate to numbers, then it will become one; otherwise it is an expression with an undefined meaning (and not even atomic which complex numbers are). -- The first expression evaluates differently because there's an internal rule for simplifying `k a1 ∈ Reals`, when `k` is real and numeric. Why not for `Complexes`? Don't know. Of course it's invalid for integers, except `- a1 ∈ Integers`, which simplifies.